# Can you take more than 1 user input on the same line?

Tags: python, input

Is there any way that I could print text, intake user input, and print something again on the same line? Kind of like this:

```
>>> I am [user_input1] years old and I am a [user_input2] person.
```

Comment: How would that look? Printing the first part of the sentence, then input, etc?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Sure there is, though you might have to use fancy terminal control codes or something.

Comment: Would you take input before the print statement, or would you print first and then take input and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to ask the user for inputs prior to printing the complete statement, then yes.

```py
print('I am',input('user_input1:'),'years old and I am a',input('user_input2:'),'person.')

#user_input1: foo
#user_input2: bar
#I am foo years old and I am a bar person.
```

Or maybe this is what you mean:

```py
print('I am [user_input1] years old and I am a [user_input2] person.')
print('I am',input('user_input1:'),'years old and I am a',input('user_input2:'),'person.')


#I am [user_input1] years old and I am a [user_input2] person.
#user_input1: foo
#user_input2: bar
#I am foo years old and I am a bar person.
```